# Unable to get values from the provider class

Tags: flutter, provider

Sorry I am new to flutter and I am stuck with this problem.
I am trying to access the value used with changeNotifier using the provider package and
just print it but it always returns null.

Main.dart

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => LoginService(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.deepOrange, accentColor: Colors.amber),
        home: HomePage(),
        routes: {ExpenseListPage.routeName: (ctx) => ExpenseListPage()},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

LoginService.dart

```
class LoginService with ChangeNotifier {
  String backendUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/login';
  UserData _userData = UserData();

  // Login
  Future<bool> login({String email, String password}) async {
    var userData = {"email": email, "password": password};
    Response response = await post('$backendUrl/login', body: userData);
    String body = response.body;
    var userObject = jsonDecode(body);
    if (userObject['token'] != null) {
      setUserData(
        name: userObject['name'],
      );
      return Future.value(true);
    }
    return Future.value(false);
  }

  setUserData({String name}) {
    _userData.name = name;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  UserData getUserData() => _userData;
}
```

New page where I try to use this after I navigate from login page

```
class ExpenseListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/userExpenseList';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var exp = Provider.of<LoginService>(context).getUserData();
    print(exp.name); // I always get null printed here
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Test'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Junior! Can you add your `UserData` class too? I'm guessing `name` is never initialized

Comment: @Nolence here is my model 
`class UserData {
  String name;
  String role;

  UserData({ this.name, this.role}); 
}`

Comment: I think I see it. You don't pass in parameters to your `UserData` class when you construct it in the second line of your LoginService therefore it will be null until you update it in your `setUserData` or login function. You can add a simple button to test things with an `onTap` of something like `Provider.of<LoginService>.setUserData(name: 'test')` to see if your `exp.name` updates

Comment: @Nolence I am updating the setUserData in the login method and I am only trying to access the getUserData after use the login method in my login page